# What happens if one DC in Cassandra runs out of physical memory?

Tags: cassandra

I'm new to cassandra and I'm asking myself what will happen if I have multiple datacenters and at one point one datacenter won't have enough physical memory to store all the data.

Assume we have 2 DCs. The first DC can store 1 TB and the second DC can only hold 500 GB. Furthermore lets say we have a replication factor = 1 for both DCs. As I understand the both DCs will have the complete token ring, so every DC will have the full data. What happens now, if I push data to DC 1 and the total amount of storage needed exceeds 500 GB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For keeping things simple, I will consider that you write the data using DC1, so this one will be the local DC in each scenario. DC2 that is down will be remote all the time. So what really matters here is what **consistency level** you are using for yours writes:

1. consistency level of type LOCAL (LOCAL_QUORUM, ONE, LOCAL_ONE) - you can write your data.
2. consistency level of type REMOTE (ALL, EACH_QUORUM, QUORUM, TWO, THREE) - you cannot write your data.

I suggest to read about [consistency levels](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html).

Also, a very quick test using ccm and cassandra-stress tool might be helpful to reproduce different scenarios.

Another comment is regarding your free space: when a node will hit the 250GB mark (half of 500GB) you will have compaction issues. The recommendation is to have half of the disk empty for compactions to run.

Let's say, however, that you will continue getting data to that node and you will hit the 500GB mark. Cassandra will stop on that node.